# Nginx Reverse Proxy - Netdata - Don't display but downlaod as application/octet-stream

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, netdata

I recently change my VPS and reinstalled everything I need, include Netdata, Nginx.
The installer works great to install Netdata. However I have some trouble to do a reverse proxy with Nginx. I already have some reverse proxy on my server and it works so the configuration should work too.

I use the official configuration of Nginx given by Netdata documentation.
https://learn.netdata.cloud/docs/agent/running-behind-nginx

So I use this configuration file:

```
upstream backend {
    # the Netdata server
    server 127.0.0.1:19999;
    keepalive 64;
}

server {
    # nginx listens to this
    listen 80;

    # the virtual host name of this
    server_name netdata.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_set_header Connection "keep-alive";
        proxy_store off;
    }
}
```

But when I go in my web browser if doesn't display Netdata Dashboard but start a download of a file as application/octet-stream.

So I need some help please

Thanks

Comment: Can you show HTTP headers from `curl -I netdata.example.com` command?

Comment: I got this reponse quite weird no ?
curl: (1) Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed

Answer (score 1):

On an other virtualhost I had an mistake made by myself.

```
listen 80 http2;
```

instead of

```
listen 80 http2;
```

just use `http2` for port 443 with tls/ssl